FILE Permission for android 14 and higher
Android.Manifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>-->

    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <!-- <meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_deactivated" android:value="@bool/FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_DEACTIVATED"/> -->
     <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@mipmap/ic_notification"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="owsapp"/>
      </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

MainActivity.java
package com.guerrilla.innov8coworking;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint;
import com.facebook.react.defaults.DefaultReactActivityDelegate;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 0;
    private String downloadUrl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final boolean setFullScreen = true;
        Log.d("Jugni", "Hii I am on create method");
        SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme, setFullScreen);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//         Check and request permissions when the app starts
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            Log.d("Jugni", "Hii I am inside version 24" + String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
            Log.d("Jugni", "Hii my permission is" + String.valueOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("Jugni", "Hii my permission is" + String.valueOf(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)));
                Log.d("Jugni", "Hii I am inside check self permission");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
                Log.d("Jugni", "Hii my new permission is" + String.valueOf(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)));
                Log.d("Jugni", "Request permission completed");
            } else {
                Log.d("Jugni", "Permission already granted");
            }
        }
    }

    private void downloadFile(String url) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setTitle("Vertretungsplan");
        request.setDescription("wird heruntergeladen");
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        String filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        manager.enqueue(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d("Jugni", "Inside Request permission block, requestCode: " + requestCode + ", permissions: " + Arrays.toString(permissions) + ", grantResults: " + Arrays.toString(grantResults));
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE) {
            Log.d("Jugni", "GrantResults length" + String.valueOf(grantResults.length));
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.d("Jugni", String.valueOf( grantResults[0]));
                Log.d("Jugni", downloadUrl);
                // Permission granted, proceed with the file download
                if (downloadUrl != null) {
                    downloadFile(downloadUrl);
                }
            } else {
                // Permission denied, handle accordingly
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
     * rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ows_app_rn";
    }
    /**
     * Returns the instance of the {@link ReactActivityDelegate}. Here we use a util class {@link
     * DefaultReactActivityDelegate} which allows you to easily enable Fabric and Concurrent React
     * (aka React 18) with two boolean flags.
     */
    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new DefaultReactActivityDelegate(
                this,
                getMainComponentName(),
                // If you opted-in for the New Architecture, we enable the Fabric Renderer.
                DefaultNewArchitectureEntryPoint.getFabricEnabled());
    }
}

Build.gradle
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"

         // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }

My app doesn't ask for file permission even after declaring and requesting it. I also tried with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and still faced the same issue. I read somewhere that WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE has been deprecated for Android 14. Can someone tell the resolution. I want to access pdf file, no audio, video or images

You are correct that android 10 does not grant the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission anymore. If you do not need other apps to access this file then your should be saving things to your apps files directory by using context.getFilesDir() then you dont need any permissions

I am talking about Android 14. How to use context.getFilesDir() ? Will I have to manually trigger to downloadFile method on the button click of download ? Is there no other approach ?
